# Can't get the value on the onItemClick of AutoCompleteTextView custom adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I am creating an app that has an `autocompletextview`, wherein the user will see suggestions as he type just like a combobox.

> What I need to accomplished.
>
> - Create a custom adapter for the AutoCompleteTextView. (ACCOMPLISHED)
> - When I typed a text, list of suggestions will appear. (ACCOMPLISHED)
> - **When I clicked that suggestion, I will be able to get it's current name same as the other information listed with it.**

Now I am having a problem with getting the current information (its ID, name, phone number, email) of the item clicked. What happens is, when I clicked an item, the current data of the first item was displayed.

Here's my getters and setters:

```
public class Contacts {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String number;

    public Contacts() {
    }

    public Contacts(String id, String name, String email, String number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Here's my custom adapter with a filter:

```
public class AutoCompleteTextViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contacts> {

        private List<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
        private List<Contacts> filteredContacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();

        public AutoCompleteTextViewAdapter(Context context, List<Contacts> contacts) {

            super(context, 0, contacts);
            this.contacts = contacts;

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return filteredContacts.size();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new ContactsFilter(this, contacts);
        }



        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            Contacts contacts = filteredContacts.get(position);
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_search_contacts_spinner, parent, false);
            TextView nameTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNameTV);
            TextView numberTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberTV);
            nameTV.setText(contacts.getName());
            numberTV.setText(contacts.getNumber());

            return convertView;

        }

        private class ContactsFilter extends Filter {

            AutoCompleteTextViewAdapter adapter;
            List<Contacts> originalList;
            List<Contacts> filteredList;

            public ContactsFilter(AutoCompleteTextViewAdapter adapter, List<Contacts> originalList) {

                super();
                this.adapter = adapter;
                this.originalList = originalList;
                this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            }

            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                filteredList.clear();
                final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    filteredList.addAll(originalList);
                } else {
                    final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                    for (final Contacts contacts : originalList) {

                        if(contacts.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                            filteredList.add(contacts);
                        }

                    }
                }

                results.values = filteredList;
                results.count = filteredList.size();
                return results;

            }

            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                adapter.filteredContacts.clear();
                adapter.filteredContacts.addAll((List) results.values);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }
    }
```

Here's the code in my oncreate method:

```
searchContactsET = findViewById(R.id.searchContactsET); //autocompletextview
searchContactsET.setThreshold(1);
searchContactsET.setAdapter(new AutoCompleteTextViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getAllContacts()));
searchContactsET.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Contacts contacts = (Contacts) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        searchContactsET.setText(contacts.getName());
        Log.i("CONTACTS: ", contacts.getName());
    }
});
```

My list under the same class with my oncreate method.

```
public List<Contacts> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    contacts.add(new Contacts("PO90", "ERIKA", "erikasong1925@gmail.com", "09324612629"));
    contacts.add(new Contacts("PO95", "JULIEZETTE", "juliesong1925@gmail.com", "09284612629"));
    return contacts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible Alternative is Store the ArrayList in your Activity as well.
Take member of Arraylist from itemselected Position.

You can declare **List contacts**  in Your Fragment of Activity.
Modify getContact method with below

```
public List<Contacts> getAllContacts() {
    contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    contacts.add(new Contacts("PO90", "ERIKA", "erikasong1925@gmail.com", "09324612629"));
    contacts.add(new Contacts("PO95", "JULIEZETTE", "juliesong1925@gmail.com", "09284612629"));
    return contacts;
}
```

Modify Item selected method with below code

```
searchContactsET = findViewById(R.id.searchContactsET); //autocompletextview
searchContactsET.setThreshold(1);
searchContactsET.setAdapter(new AutoCompleteTextViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getAllContacts()));
searchContactsET.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Contacts contact = contacts.get(i);
        searchContactsET.setText(contacts.getName());
        Log.i("CONTACTS: ", contacts.getName());
    }
});
```

I think this will resolve your issue.